# Why can function parameter contain addresses or variables in C

Tags: c, mpi, pass-by-reference, memory-address

Looking up some tutorials online I noticed two different MPI_SEND uses:

The first says the start of the buffer is `&a[500]`:

```
MPI_Send(&a[500], 500, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The second says the start of the buffer is `b`:

```
MPI_Send(b, 500, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I'm very new to `C` so maybe it has something to do with pass by reference / value.

My guess is that `b` is the same as `&b`, but in the first case swe use `&a[500]` because we are starting with an address in the middle of an array??

But why can't you just say `a[500]` instead of `&a[500]`?

Comment: Short: because `a[500]` will pass *the element's value* instead of its address.

Comment: Assuming the program also contains a line `void* b = &a[500];`, there is no magic going on.

Comment: `b` is not the same as `&b`. If `b` is an array, then `&b` is a pointer to an array, which has different semantics than a pointer to the first element of an array, though the only thing that interests `MPI_Send`, namely the address, will be the same. If `b` is a pointer, then `&b` is a pointer to a pointer and carries a completely different address - passing it to `MPI_Send` will most likely result in garbage or a crash. On the other hand, `b` is equivalent to `&b[0]`. One says that an array name decays to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term `&a[500]` is the address of `a[500]`, that is the 500st element of the array a.  So it is a pointer.

The term `b` can be either an array (e.g. `int b[1000]`) in which case, without index, it is converted to the pointer to the start of the array (i.e.  `&b[0]` ),  or a p real pointer, pointing to the start of some array.

Remarks:   `a[500]` (without the ampersand) would be the value of the 500st element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes sense

Answer (score 4):

First things first: The `&` operator is the address of operator, while the `*` operator is the dereference operator. The `&` operator gets the address of the operand, while the `*` operator gets the value of the variable at the operand's value. These operators are inverses of each other. In C, an array is almost like a pointer. A pointer is a variable with the address of another variable set to it. A few differences between a pointer and an array can be found [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-5/) When you do `int arr[10]`, you are allocating 10 `int`s worth of memory, and then setting the variable `arr` to the address of the beginning of that piece of allocated memory. For example:

```
                     |               allocated memory
                     |,---------------------/\-------------------------.
Address (hex):   arr |           012C |   0130 |   0134 | ... |   0170 |
Value (hex)  :  012C | arr[0] or *arr | arr[1] | arr[2] | ... | arr[9] |

&arr[2] = 0x0134
```

Something to note: `arr[i]` is the same as `*(arr + i)`.

In your question, you pass `&a[500]` to MPI_Send. This is indeed a pass by reference. `&a[500]` is the address of the 500th element of `a`. What is being passed to the first call of `MPI_Send` is an address. If, in the tutorial, `b` is a pointer to a buffer, then the address stored in b is what is being passed on the second call of `MPI_Send`.

Comment: Very nice detailed explanation. Thanks